# bootstrap container margin is modified when I don't need it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I don't understand what's going on, I have a container class applied to a div, margins work perfectly, but when the content within the div exceed the height of the viewport (scroll bar shows up) the container modifies automatically left and right margins... so when navigating through my HTML files I can notice this particular HTML has different margins values...

To replicate this behaviour you need to add an extra lorem300 to the div.

```
<section id="turnos">
        <div id="turno-titulo">
            <h3 class="mx-2">Turnos Octubre</h3>
            <p class="mx-2">En esta seccion se detallan los turnos a cumplirse durante Octubre</p>
        </div>
        <div id="turno-tabla">
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, assumenda quaerat sequi, dignissimos voluptates vero odio omnis quas, quisquam doloremque consequatur dicta veritatis quibusdam recusandae. Odit velit tenetur nam quam blanditiis, sed quis facere doloribus obcaecati a iure accusamus est nemo soluta unde repellendus deserunt voluptatibus quas consequatur iusto porro. Ut, voluptate maiores. Sunt eos culpa, amet error sint repellat sed temporibus, quia harum perferendis nam. Doloribus quia laboriosam minus nobis nesciunt nisi? Deleniti ab numquam et facere aliquam, quaerat explicabo. Eius totam est temporibus sed! Vel error, illo eligendi officia assumenda nulla tenetur iste, nobis atque magni veniam in delectus autem id inventore deserunt repudiandae ab, consectetur molestias. Quasi tempora placeat facere, reiciendis dicta accusantium debitis corporis? Aperiam vero, velit dolor, dignissimos, optio ea fuga quidem obcaecati ad autem aspernatur odio suscipit ab eveniet atque. Sit esse quibusdam omnis nihil corrupti magni sapiente dolore debitis, nesciunt quis. Tempora atque quisquam, deleniti voluptatem repellendus dignissimos quibusdam veritatis magnam laborum asperiores fugiat maxime quas numquam eos consequatur autem. Tenetur amet quia, repudiandae beatae facilis exercitationem deserunt aliquid, voluptatum iusto quisquam eveniet quam! Expedita pariatur itaque in voluptatum consequuntur facilis asperiores unde, quasi, assumenda commodi, delectus ullam harum. Rem aspernatur voluptatum expedita, assumenda, eligendi dolorum amet iure, error veniam corrupti sit repellat eius odio sed suscipit incidunt ut beatae molestias labore? Repudiandae vel iure sequi ducimus tempore, vero enim nemo sapiente laboriosam assumenda id! Assumenda eius, ad quos nesciunt aliquid possimus tenetur, quibusdam ratione nostrum sequi nisi. Nesciunt tempore fuga itaque ipsam debitis, atque iure ex earum cum totam sunt excepturi labore numquam corrupti, expedita harum praesentium iste assumenda quos porro? Quo asperiores, earum velit, praesentium ipsum consequatur perferendis ullam, illum atque voluptate a. Fugit exercitationem facere repellendus voluptatem maiores impedit deleniti ducimus, officia, numquam soluta similique aliquam modi assumenda deserunt ullam.
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Waht do you mean with _container modifies automatically left and right margins_?

Comment: You need add full snippet to understand your question. Question is not clear for me.

Comment: @Sfili_81 if you duplicate the div that is within #turno-tabla until it gets higher than the viewport height, the .container div slightly modifies the left and right margin automatically, and I couldn't find any media query within bootstrap css that is generating that change

Comment: Add a working snippet to reproduce the issue